# Casting a superclass object into a subclass object in java

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

```
public VIPCustomer getRealVIPCustomer(String ID) {
        VIPCustomer vipCustomer = new VIPCustomer(ID);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Customer> vipCustomerCheck : allCustomers.entrySet()) {
            if (vipCustomer.equals(vipCustomerCheck.getValue()) && vipCustomerCheck instanceof VIPCustomer) {
                return (VIPCustomer) vipCustomerCheck.getValue();
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

For some reason I always get null using this method , and I can't figure out why.
I have looked at similar questions , and could really find an answer that will help me.

`allCustomers` is a hashmap and `VIPCustomer` is a subclass of `Customer`.

Comment: Well most probably because all entries in `allCustomers` are not of type `VIPCustomer`, thus the `if` is never entered.

Comment: There are only 3 possibilities of why that method could return null: 1. either `allCustomers` is empty and the loop over the entry set never runs or 2. your if condition is never met and the if-block never entered or 3. `vipCustomerCheck.getValue()` returns null. I recommend trying to find out which one is the case in your code